# UIView removeFromSuperview causes app to crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, memory-leaks

Let me explain my problem. I have 3 `UIView`: a **LoginView**, **LibraryView**, and a **StoreView**. I have this code to switch from one UIView to another:

```
- (void)showView:(NSInteger)viewTag
{
  if (viewTag == 1)
  {
      if (self.loginView)
      {
        self.loginView = nil;
        self.loginView.delegate = nil;
      }

      LoginView *loginPage = [[LoginView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
      [loginPage setDelegate:self];

      self.loginView = loginPage;

      [loginPage release];

      [self.view addSubview:self.loginView];
}
else if(viewTag == 2)
{
    if (self.libraryView)
    {
        self.libraryView = nil;
        self.libraryView.delegate = nil;
    }

    LibraryView *libraryPage = [[LibraryView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [libraryPage setDelegate:self];

    self.libraryView = libraryPage;

    [libraryPage release];

    [self.view addSubview:self.libraryView];
}
else
{
    if (self.bookStoreView)
    {
        self.bookStoreView = nil;
        self.bookStoreView.delegate = nil;
    }

    BookStoreView *bookStore = [[BookStoreView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [bookStore setDelegate:self];

    self.bookStoreView = bookStore;

    [bookStore release];

    [self.view addSubview:self.bookStoreView];
}
```

}

Basically, that is how I initialize the UIViews. And here are the buttons used to switch between them:

```
- (void)loginViewToLibraryView
  {
     [self.loginView removeFromSuperview];
     [self showView:2];
  }

- (void)libraryViewToStoreView
  {
     [self.libraryView removeFromSuperview];
     [self showView:3];
  }

  //so on...
```

The problem arises when the I call the function `libraryViewToLoginView` and `storeViewToLoginView`. The app crashes whenever I call these functions, which is weird because the two functions worked properly before. I checked Profile and it gave me this stack trace:

```
#   Address     Category Event RefCt  Timestamp    Size Responsible Library   Responsible Caller
0   0xc4dcac0   CALayer Malloc  1   00:02.233.004   48  UIKit                 -[UIView _createLayerWithFrame:]
1   0xc4dcac0   CALayer Retain  3   00:02.238.317   0   QuartzCore             CA::Layer::insert_sublayer(CA::Transaction*, CALayer*, unsigned long)
2   0xc4dcac0   CALayer Release 2   00:02.238.324   0   UIKit                 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:]
3   0xc4dcac0   CALayer Retain  3   00:02.238.518   0   QuartzCore            -[CALayerArray copyWithZone:]
4   0xc4dcac0   CALayer Release 2   00:02.238.602   0   UIKit                 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:]
5   0xc4dcac0   CALayer Retain  3   00:02.238.665   0   QuartzCore            -[CALayerArray copyWithZone:]
6   0xc4dcac0   CALayer Release 2   00:02.238.796   0   UIKit                 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:]
7   0xc4dcac0   CALayer Retain  3   00:05.107.397   0   QuartzCore            -[CALayerArray copyWithZone:]
8   0xc4dcac0   CALayer Release 2   00:05.107.539   0   UIKit                 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:]
9   0xc4dcac0   CALayer Retain  3   00:05.107.613   0   QuartzCore            -[CALayerArray copyWithZone:]
10  0xc4dcac0   CALayer Release 2   00:05.107.700   0   UIKit                 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:]
11  0xc4dcac0   CALayer Retain  2   00:06.105.958   0   QuartzCore            -[CALayerArray copyWithZone:]
12  0xc4dcac0   CALayer Release 2   00:06.108.134   0   UIKit                 -[UIView dealloc]
13  0xc4dcac0   CALayer Release 1   00:06.108.492   0   UIKit                 -[UIView dealloc]
14  0xc4dcac0   CALayer Zombie  -1  00:06.115.332   0   QuartzCore            CA::release_objects(X::List<void const*>*)
```

As you can see, it is a bunch of calls on the CALayer which I don't really understand. I want to understand why is this happening. Can anyone explain?

Comment: You have a Zombie process = you're releasing deallocated object. Try use Instruments to analyze memory leaks. Show us @property of loginView and libraryView, are they strong/retain ?

Comment: did you try releasing the recently created views after you add them as subviews? I'm not very familiar with pre-ARC obj c but, afaik adding subviews to views create new strong references so maybe you can swap these lines (and similar ones):
    [bookStore release];

    [self.view addSubview:self.bookStoreView];

Comment: I just would like to know whether `loginView`, `libraryView` and `bookStoreView` are having retain properties?

Comment: All the mentioned views are retained properties. I will now swap the codes as mentioned by Hermann in the answer section and see if it will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frankly I have not understood everything that you want to achieve here. But you should consider the sequence of events. See my comments:

```
  if (self.loginView)
  {
    self.loginView = nil;
    //self.loginView is nil now. What so you think doese happen on the next line? 
    self.loginView.delegate = nil;
    // change the sequence of this lines and it will be ok. 
  }

  LoginView *loginPage = [[LoginView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
  [loginPage setDelegate:self];

  self.loginView = loginPage;

  [loginPage release]; //here you release the object. it is gone now. However, there are still references to it. 

  [self.view addSubview:self.loginView]; // here you add the released object. What do you expect to happen? 
  // Switch those two statmetns and you should be fine.
```

Well, it may even work as those statmens are next to each other. And when you remove it from its super view it gets released again. And there your app might crash.

BTW, without having it retained you should not release it at all. Or am I wrong here? However, addSubview should retain it and removeFromSuperview will release it, so no additional release would be required. Onece removed it should be gone. (If not retained somewhere else)

Comment: Thanks for the response! In all honesty though, I don't really fully understand it. I inherited it from another programmer and I'm still in the process of learning the flow. So thanks for helping me out! I'll accept your answer if it works.

Comment: All right. It is older code then? That is why you do not use Automatic Reference Counting? For new projects you should consider using it. A lot of that pain caused by memory management is gone then.

Comment: Yes actually. I tried to convert it to ARC using the Refactor in Xcode, but some it says there are things that prevents it from converting. I don't have much time to find those things just to convert to ARC so I decided to leave it as it is for now.

Comment: I have an additional question. The `loginPage` was assigned to `self.loginView` before it was released, then the `self.loginView` was added as a subview. Shouldn't the `self.loginView` retained the `loginPage`?

Comment: I never tried that because I would use the opposite sequence. Releasing first then adding as sub view would work for sure when the retain count is 1 or more (meaning: when it is retained by some other code at the same time). I could guess that it still would work even if the retain count is 0 because it is added as subview and retained there directly after its release. But I would not bet on that.

Comment: Yes, it is wise to leave it without ARC for the moment. Before converting an existing project from non-ARC to ARC, even automatically, you should have fully understood both concepts. Otherwise you will almost certainly run into quite painful debugging situations. For the time beeing deal with the non-ACR and apply proper retain/relase/autorelease circles.